# Dependency Properties - What's the point of having 2 owners?

Tags: wpf, selector, dependency-properties, tabitem

If you look at `Selector` and `TabItem` classes they apparently both own the `IsSelectedProperty`.

```
static Selector()
{
    ...
    IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(Selector), ...);
    ...
}

static TabItem()
{
    IsSelectedProperty = Selector.IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TabItem), ...);
    ...
}
```

So I guess my question is... since the Tabitem contains the actual propertychanged logic, what is the point of the IsSelectedProperty even residing in the `Selector` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, `Selector` has the `IsSelected` DP because there are a number of controls that derive from it whose items can be selected (`ComboBox`, `ListBox`, `ListView`, `TabControl`, `DataGrid`). They all need an ability to mark an item with `IsSelected`, therefore that DP is declared in their common base class. Like Tim said, DRY.

Another reason that `TabItem` adds itself as an owner is that in the `Selector` class, `IsSelected` is an attached property because you can have just about anything as an item in a `Selector`. Attached properties are pretty mobile that way.

However, `TabItem` adds itself as an owner such that it is not an attached property on `TabItem`. It also registers a callback method to be called when the value changes so that it can do a few things when selected or unselected.

And yes, it is easier to type `<TabItem` and see `IsSelected` in Intellisense rather than going, "But how the heck do I make one selected?" and have to hunt around and find that you need to use an attached property from some other class.

Comment: So basically it is defined in the Selector class to give it wide availability to be used on multiple controls, but the TabItem takes ownership of it so that it can register callbacks when the values change and also to avoid `<TabItem Selector.IsSelected="..." />`? Also, you're saying that Selector marks it as an AttachedProperty because it is just there to own it for other properties to use, not so much that it is a property that is used within a Selector instance.

Comment: Pretty much. It isn't _visibly_ used by `Selector`s, but indirectly through their items and internally (think multiple selection toggling). `ListBoxItem` and `DataGridRow` also use callbacks (and `ListViewItem` inherits from `ListBoxItem`). Having a single original instance of `IsSelectedDependencyProperty` adheres to design and philosophy of the whole dependency property system, since `IsSelected` has the exact same use and meaning in all those contexts. There are also `SelectedEvent`, `UnselectedEvent`, etc. (`ListBoxItem` does `AddOwner` on them, for example).

Answer (score 1):

It's basically just an instance of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Here's a thread from MSDN forums on the topic:

[DependencyProperty.AddOwner - What's the Point](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/086e3ced-b3b7-4984-b9c4-43cb8a6b620e/)

Comment: That seems to make sense except for the fact that in this example the original property was registered as an attached property. That combination just doesn't seem to make sense because an attached property usually entails doing something like `<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" />`. In this example you'd just do `<TabItem IsSelected="True" />` as apposed to `<TabItem Selector.IsSelected="True" />`?

Comment: See Joel B Fant's answer for further clarification on what changes when TabItem adds itself as an Owner.